# Is lazy approval possible with Microsoft Flow?

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, flow

I have used some third party tools such as nintex workflows where users can send and email with a keyword approved or yes and the workflow gets approved and status field gets updated.

can i do the same with Microsoft flow ?

Answer (score 4):

**Yes, so long as your recipient is using Outlook 2016 or Outlook Web app**

Microsoft has named this feature "Actionable Messages".

To implement this, you would add a "Start Content Approval" action in Flow, which will send out approval request emails.  All recipients will receive an email that can be approved or rejected (with comments) without leaving Outlook:

[image]

Approvers that are using earlier versions of Outlook will still receive the email - however, they will be directed to the Microsoft Flow site to action the request.

The following Microsoft blog post describes in more detail: [Respond to your approvals from your inbox and Set an Approval Expiry](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/actionable-messages-approvals/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes , you can do the Lazy Approval Workflow using Flow. I did it in one of our project. I have tested it in Exchange Web version, not in Outlook desktop version.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that using a MS Flow.

You can add a condition to classify the keyword value and then start an approval request based on the value.

An official article for your reference:
[Create an approval request](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/flow/guided-learning/work-with-approvals#step-1)

Comment: That link appears to be dead, do you have an updated one?