# Power Automate - Can I embed fields from PowerApps form into body of Email?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, power-automate, powerapps-forms, email-notification

I have a SharePoint list with a PowerApps form that goes through an approval process via notification emails from Power Automate.  I ran a demo the other day and was informed that for one reason or another, some individuals won't have the ability to navigate to the SharePoint list (permissions/security it seems), but they still need to view the form and select Approve or Not Approve from a drop down field.  So my question is, can I embed a drop down field in the body of a Power Automate email that a user can edit and submit data directly from that email?  The user would receive the email in Outlook, open the email, Approve from a drop-down field in the email, then submit?  I have a Submit button with a lot of actions built in directly on the Form.  So if I can just embed the whole form, I'd think they could do this without having to navigate to SP.

Is this at all possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Only embedding the form will not work obviously if they don't have access to SharePoint list to make changes to column values. You can create a another small app for capturing the user decision and then update the original list with this data. Also, if you just want to give few options in email, you can do that using same Power automate flow, capture response and then update original list without creating a new app.

Comment: If I use Send an Email with Options, can I still modify the Sender?  I don't want those emails to have my name displayed.  Alternatively, could I embed a simple Checkbox, or Yes/No within the body of the email?

Comment: You can use shared mailbox to send email notification in that case

Comment: Would it be possible for me to add fields to an email that comes from the PowerApps form instead?

Comment: Maybe you can make use of 'Outlook Actionable Messages'. Check this https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/240710/is-lazy-approval-possible-with-microsoft-flow